# Cloud Functions for Firebase: spawn ImageMagick syntax

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I want to get height and width of image uploaded to firebase storage using imagemagick using cloud functions.

I wrote following code:

```
var child = spawn('identify', ["-ping","-format","`%w %h`",tempLocalFile]);
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
    //Here is where the output goes
});
child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
    //Here is where the error output goes
});
```

But firebase log shows error:

```
Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
at mkdirp.then.then (/user_code/index.js
```

Please suggest how to write Imagemagick and get output of the execution.

Comment: Your error is showing a problem with "mkdirp", but I don't see that anywhere in the code you've shown.  Are you sure the problem isn't elsewhere in the code that's not shown?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue `Cannot read property 'on' of undefined` stems from how you are adding the `stdout` and `stderr` listeners. You have to fetch the process and add the listeners to *that*, not directly to the promise that `spawn` returns. Code snippet:

```
var spawnPromise = spawn('identify', ["-ping","-format","`%w %h`",tempLocalFile]);
var childProcess = spawnPromise.childProcess;
childProcess.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
    //Here is where the output goes
});
childProcess.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
    //Here is where the error output goes
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case you're using `('child-proces-promise').spawn` as the [firebase thumbnail sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/f3320e3217737d73f998b93c7227e0d1988cc6e1/quickstarts/thumbnails/functions/index.js), you must notice it returns a promise, and the child process can be accessed with the `childProcess` property.

```
var promise = spawn('identify', ["-ping","-format","`%w %h`",tempLocalFile]);
var child = promise.childProcess;

child.stdout.on('data', function(data) { // do something });
child.stderr.on('data', function(data) { // do something });
```